# Javascript async iterables for loop guaranteed to finish in order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have a for await loop like follows:

```
const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      next() {
        if (this.i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: this.i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};

for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
  await someAsyncFunction(); // (*)
  console.log(num);
}
```

In this case, are the numbers guaranteed to be printed out in the expected order? In other words, is each iteration of the for loop guaranteed to finish executing before the next one starts, even if the for loop itself contains async calls such as the line marked by (*)?

Comment: Think of await as a sort of "do not continue until you complete this step"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This has nothing to do with asynchronous iterations, it is true for every kind of control flow statement - including loops - that it pauses on `await` statements.

There is nothing about `for await` loops that somehow makes their iterations run concurrently.